# Does the delta v requirement of a rocket to place a satellite in orbit depend on the position of other planets?

Tags: launch, orbit, artificial-satellite, delta-v

Does the necessary delta v given to a satellite (earth orbiting) by the rocket during its launch depend on the positions of other planets? Please justify your answer.

Comment: More clarification is needed here... are you only referring to interplanetary probes, or *any* satellite, including Earth-orbiting? If it's the latter, then the answer is simply no.

Comment: If you consider lunar and jovian perturbations, the short answer is **yes**. However, the scale of those perturbations is much less than uncertainty in rocket performance.

Comment: The answer is strictly yes, but practically no per @PearsonArtPhoto 's response.

Comment: If you're sending to other than just Earth orbit, the position of the target bodie(s) (Moon, other planets) would determine the launch **window**, in order to minimize the boost (speed) needed to get there, or conversely, allow for a larger payload. Launching outside the window requires more fuel burn (for course corrections). This has very very little to do with _gravitational_ effects at launch, as discussed in other answers. "Please justify your answer" -- is this homework?

Answer (score 8):

Not really. Here's the effect that a few major bodies would have, depending on the direction launched, expressed in the unit of Newtons/kg. Note that 9.8 N/kg is the equivalent of Earth's gravity. I used [this calculator](http://www.ajdesigner.com/phpgravity/newtons_law_gravity_equation_force.php), and [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_by_size).

```
Sun       0.00593
Moon      5.554E-9
Jupiter   1.352E-7 to 3.664E-7
```

Bottom line, it might be beneficial to launch at noon, but there won't be much of a difference really no matter what you do. These are extremely small, and really just don't make much of a difference. 0.1% of the Earth's gravity at the surface is negligible. Put another way, Earth's gravity at sea level is about 9.8201024640745, 1km higher is 9.8170204389969, for a difference of 0.0030820250776. That's about half of the effect of the sun, a very small effect indeed.

The requirements change considerably if you plan on leaving Earth Orbit, but I won't get too much in to that complexity.